# Mariadb : Group by failed with emojis in varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci column

Tags: mariadb

I have a table with emojis like this :

```
MariaDB> SELECT HEX(value), value FROM `emojis`;
+----------------------------+-------+
| HEX(value)                 | value |
+----------------------------+-------+
| F09F9AA9                   |      |
| F09F8FB4                   |      |
| E29C94EFB88F               | ✔️    |
| F09F9AA9                   |      |
| F09F8FB4                   | ‍♀️     |
| F09FA79BE2808DE29980EFB88F |   |
+----------------------------+-------+
```

But when I add a group by, some values are not returned :

```
MariaDB> SELECT value, HEX(value) FROM `emojis` GROUP BY value;
+-------+----------------------------+
| value | HEX(value)                 |
+-------+----------------------------+
| ✔️     | E29C94EFB88F               |
| ‍♀️    | F09F9AA9                   |
|     | F09FA79BE2808DE29980EFB88F |
+-------+----------------------------+
```

The black flag and the kiss are missing. It looks like MariaDB can not do a group by with UTF8 MB4 characters.

My column type is : varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL;

I tried with Mariadb 10.1 and 10.5, and got the same result.

Is this a bug or am I missing something ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HEX` is not an aggregate function, so you cannot use as one with `GROUP BY`. If you wish to get the different emojis and the respective hex-values use `DISTINCT`.

You [should](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html) (see Character Collating Weights) store the emojis as `utf8mb4_bin` instead `utf8mb4_unicode_ci`. The reason for this is how the character's collating weight is determined. See handling of comparision of characters with [WEIGTH_STRING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_weight-string)-function.

```
SELECT DISTINCT value, HEX(value) 
FROM emojis;
```

See [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVvupKEWxYYzHVer5BtSk/5)

The query like this should not be used:

```
SELECT value
FROM emojis
GROUP BY value;
```

The `GROUP BY` should be used only when you mix normal columns with aggregate functions. As said, use `DISTINCT` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle, I updated to add failing queries, as an example : [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bVvupKEWxYYzHVer5BtSk/4).
But isn't it weird that the engine can not see that 2 emojis are not the same ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to your answers I understand what difference it makes to use `utf8mb4_bin` or `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` when using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` and other functions comparing strings.

But in my case I could not change the encoding of my column, but I learned that collations could be specified in request, like this :

```
SELECT id, value
FROM `emojis`
GROUP BY value COLLATE utf8mb4_bin;
```

Warning this is not working if `sql_mode` is `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY`.

Answer (score 0):

The collation of Emoji changed at some point in the history of Unicode.  The older collation `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` (version 4.0) treated them as equal.  Newer collation `utf8mb4_unicode_520` (version 5.20) treated them as unequal.

`GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY` and `<` depend on collation.